# EnumDisplayMonitors EnumProc Callback

Tags: c++, windows, api, winapi

How do I pass and return the pointer to `dwData` in `EnumDisplayMonitors`?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL CALLBACK MyInfoEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData) {

    dwData = ((LPARAM)&hMonitor);
    return true;
}

void main()
{
    TCHAR* monitorHandle[100];
    EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, MyInfoEnumProc, (LPARAM)(&monitorHandle));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the `dwData` parameter to its intended pointer type and then de-reference it to assign to it as shown below..

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL CALLBACK MyInfoEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{    
    *reinterpret_cast<HMONITOR*>(dwData) = hMonitor;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    HMONITOR monitorHandle = NULL;
    EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, MyInfoEnumProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&monitorHandle));
    printf("%p", monitorHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

In main, we are passing a pointer to a `HMONITOR` (aka the address of `monitorHandle`). Then in the callback, we cast the `dwData` parameter back to an `HMONITOR` pointer. We dereference it to assign to it and then print it in main to check if it was assigned properly or if it is still `NULL`.

Btw, main always returns an integer!

Comment: Thanks! I easily get confused.